# Folders inherent to Dagger have been created

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt

In my Android project I imported Dagger Hilt 2 as expected but I notice that the following folders were created:

[image]

Is it normal for them to be visible or is there a way to prevent them from being visible?

Comment: Dagger (and Hilt as an extension of Dagger) generates code when your project is built. This code is placed in the build directory of your application/module. The generated code is what allows Dagger to provide dependencies at runtime.

Comment: @HezyZiv thanks for your attention, is there a way in Android Studio to hide them from view?

Comment: Right-click on a directory and select "Mark Directory as" -> "Excluded". This will hide the directory from your typical view, but be careful with this as it can sometimes have unintended side-effects (e.g., during search). The "Excluded" action is primarily meant for directories you don't want the IDE to index, like build outputs.

I would not do that